# init.d script worked OK on Ubuntu 10.10 but not on 11.10 despite LBS header correction

Tags: ubuntu, service, upstart, init.d, sysv

On Ubuntu 11.10, if I run  **/usr/bin/cserver -c /etc/cserver.conf &** it'll work fine.

But if I run **service cserver start** or **/etc/init.d/cserver start** as I did on 10.10, it won't. It just says "starting cServer", and that's the last I hear of it.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cserver
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $time
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the cserver server daemon
# Description:       Controls the cserver server daemon
### END INIT INFO
#
set -e
set -u
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

CSERVERDIR=/usr/bin
PROG=./cserver
OPTIONS=" -c /etc/cserver.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

start() {
          echo -n "Starting cServer "
          cd $CSERVERDIR
      daemon $PROG $OPTIONS
          RETVAL=$?
          echo
          return $RETVAL
}
stop() {
          CSERVERPID=$(pidof cserver)
          if [ $CSERVERPID ] ; then
        echo -n "Stopping cServer "
            kill $(pidof cserver)
            RETVAL=$?
          else
            echo "cServer not running"
            RETVAL=1
          fi
          echo
          return $RETVAL
}
status() {
          CSERVERPID=$(pidof cserver)
          if [ $CSERVERPID ] ; then
            echo -n "cServer is running"
            RETVAL=0
          else
            echo -n "cServer is stopped"
            RETVAL=1
          fi
          echo
          return $RETVAL
}

# See how we were called.
RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  status)
        status
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Although I never had to do this on the original server, and sysv-rc-conf showed it present in the list and starting at the right levels, I manually tried doing the update-rc.d and it complained about an invalid lsb header, which led me to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/113032/how-to-conform-to-update-rc-d-with-lsb-standard) and [guide](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). So I changed the header as above, and here's what it looked like before:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# chkconfig: 345 99 99
#
# description: cserver init
# processname: cserver

# Source function library.
# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

Now, there's that line about "Source function library", but that directory doesn't even exist and the line is commented out anyway.

I've checked the permissions and symlinks etc on the old server, and everything seems identical.

A little bit dazed and confused now - perhaps a fresh and more knowledgaeble pair of eyes can spot something here? Thanks.

**UPDATE and EDIT:** Thanks kubankczyk - I went for your suggestion of copying another found the nginx startup script to be the simplest, and ended up with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cserver
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the cserver server
# Description:       starts cserver using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/cserver
NAME=cserver
DESC=cserver
DAEMON_OPTS=" -c /etc/cserver.conf"

#test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
set -e
#set -u
#${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

. /lib/lsb/init-functions


case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
            --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;

    stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /var/run/$NAME.pid \
            --exec $DAEMON || true
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;

    restart|force-reload)
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
            /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON || true
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
            /var/run/$NAME.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS || true
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;

    status)
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/$NAME.pid "$DAEMON" cserver && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Not sure whether it's correct, but at least it starts the service! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has been written for chkconfig (such as used in Suse Linux) not for update-rc.d.
The best you can do now (if you don't want to use chkconfig) is to pick some simple script from your /etc/init.d, read it, understand it, copy it and change to run cserver.

In particular, verify that the command "daemon" is used properly in your script in conjunction with ampersand &.

Start troubleshooting the simplest scenario. Change temporarily the OPTIONS to OPTIONS=" -c /etc/cserver.conf". Test only the bare script (if this doesn't work, the `service cserver start` won't work whether header is LSB or not):

```
  su -
  export DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG=1
  /etc/init.d/cserver start
```

(edit question with the results)

Comment: Info added as reqested - I did try your script, but if put out pages and pages of stuff with + next to some of it. As I resolved it by your other suggestion, I pasted that instead. Thanks! Although I'm still baffled as to why that previous version worked perfectly on 10.10 and not 11.10...